# Unique fixed point of contraction defined on a ball

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

In the case where $f : X \rightarrow X$ is not a contraction on the whole space $X$, but
rather a contraction on some neighborhood of a given point $y$, In this case we restrict our function to a certain open ball $B_{r}(y)$ so that $f : B_{r}(y)\rightarrow X$ is contraction map with contraction constant $h < 1$ and we assume that $d(y, f (y)) < r(1−h)$. Then, $f$ has a unique fixed point in the ball.
Is this fixed point global? or does the fixed point change if you change the ball? and is this ball also unique?

Comment: What is the difference between a global and a local fixed point?

Comment: For distinct $y$'s with the same property (but not sharing such a neighborhood) it could be possible to get different fixed points. When $y$ is fixed and balls with radius $r_1, r_2$ satisfy the hypothesis, then since the fixed point is unique in the bigger ball, it must be the same in the smaller ball as well.

Comment: thank you Berci